# Stop android browser from loading URL

Tags: android, browser, browser-history, android-browser, redirect

Is there any way to stop android native browser from being loading specific URL (eg. xyz.com) provided by my app and show notification about blocking ? If we can't stop then how to redirect browser to that another HTML page like otherPage.html (that is saved in sdcard) whenever xyz.com is visited?

I am busting my head into for many days with lot of searching, but no luck so far.

Any example/tutorial would be great.

Bundle Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WebViewClient and "filter" specific url:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
     if(url.equals("xyz.com")){
       view.loadUrl("www.otherurl.com");
     }
     return false; //we handle url loading on our webview
   }
});
```

Comment: Actually, user is visiting URL in android browser and my app reads browsing history of last visited URL. If URL is xyz.com then app has to alert the user and block it from being loading in future. I am new to android, so does above code applicable to my scenario.

Comment: I don't think that you can alterate the behavior of another application in the way you are describing. Yes, you can alert the user but you can't stop him from loading this url...

Comment: So we can alert user by re-directing to otherURL.com using code in your answer. Right?

Comment: The code works if the user is inside your app and is navigating using a webview.

Comment: how can we redirect to otherPage.html whenever xyz.com is visited in android default browser.? Any one has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This may work using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). Whenever an app opens an URL, a specific intent is created and the browser catches it. And on my device, the standard browser creates intents and catches them itself every time, even if I just click on a link inside the browser window.

So just write a small app which catches the browser intents (the link above and [vogel/a](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#exercise_intentfilter) should help), compares the given URL with the blacklist and either displays the warning or forwards the intent to the browser.
Now the user just has to specify your app as standard for this type of intent and then you should be fine.